# BadImageFormatException when running F# application

Tags: .net, f#, f#-3.0, badimageformatexception

Using VS2013 with .NET 4.0 I've compiled sample code provided at [Updated version of "TrueSkill Through Time" Bayesian Inference Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2012/04/19/updated-version-of-quot-trueskill-through-time-quot-bayesian-inference-code.aspx).

However when I try to run it against small data set `ChessAnalysis.exe SmallChessBase.csv` I always get `System.BadImageFormatException` when it gets to "running the schedule".

I've tried compiling application as Any CPU, x64, x86 and AnyCPU Prefer 32-bit, but nothing helped.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Is Windows XP involved here at all?

Comment: @HansPassant, no Windows XP, running on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I've gotten this error when including a native DLL as a resource in my assembly. Changing the Build Action to "None" solved it for me. (Might not apply - but being a vague question, it's difficult to provide specific answers.)

Comment: @JDB it doesn't reference anything but standard libraries. If you have VS perhaps you could try compiling sources from the blog post yourself to see if you can spot anything?

Comment: I forked the code to make it work on Ubuntu 16.04 with Mono. If that's a possibility for you, check out https://github.com/lucasmaystre/ChessAnalysis. I included simple installation instructions.